# install windows service in custom actions

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-installer, custom-action

I have created a c# 4.0 windows service. I have created an installer project (.msi) for it which installs the service to a particular folder.

To automate the process fully, I would like to install the service as part of the custom actions I have for my installer.

How can I code my custom actions to install or when uninstalling the msi, uninstall the windows service?

Comment: Please note that installer projects (.vdproj) won't be supported in Studio 2011, so it's best to switch to WiX before you get too far into it. The .wixproj file has studio support, and is MSBuild compliant. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx

Comment: [Installing a service using WiX](http://goo.gl/qG1a7)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ServiceInstaller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller.aspx) class. A quick solution would be to find `installutil` tool and execute it against your Service.exe, but you have to capture the output to see whether the installation succeeded or not and you don't have much control over `Install`, `Commit`, `Rollback`, and `Uninstall` phases.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: don't. The proper way is to install it using the MSI database itself, i.e. [`ServiceInstall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371637.aspx) and [`ServiceControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371634.aspx) tables. Every single "convenient" IDE for MSI creation and also WiX come with primitives to make use of this builtin facility.

The very reason that this is **best practice**, just like including the COM registration in your MSI instead of calling `DllRegisterServer` of the COM (DLL) to register is that your application *may* be defunct at the time the user attempts to remove it.

The database actions can still be executed even by a newer Windows Installer, say after an upgrade of Windows itself, while your code may refuse to run or may not run for other reasons.

Comment: I came with the same problem . I Have a custom action that will generate a set of properties and that properties to be substituted in the service config xml. But then wix starts the service before The custom action executes.So the config file has the same old values. I have Created a stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043204/how-to-update-xml-with-properties-added-by-the-custom-action/40051322 Can you help me out with this ?